# Create a solution (single package) to load these three different format file into single target SQL server table

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

A folder contains same structured file (same column count, order and information) in three different format (.xls, .xlsx & .txt). Create a solution (single package) to load these three different format file into single target SQL server table dynamically. SSIS Package.

Can someone help me with step by step process

Comment: You have te create 3 data flow and check the file extension to execute the right one. If you need help I can show you step by step

Comment: @Riadhovic..Yes please can you help me with step by step process